# MySql performance doctor: someone can translate this values for me?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

```
Slow_queries 11
Select_full_join 13 k
Handler_read_next 203 k
Handler_read_rnd_next 5,174 M
Created_tmp_disk_tables 53 k
Opened_tables 59 k
```

this are the RED flagged values i found on my mysql status...I'm a self-taught developer so i'm not sure how to fix it or i those values are really high or what...the description given in phpmyadmin is not always clear to me...

NOTE: my website is still on staging os there is no web traffic besides my tests

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to optimize your MySQL queries. To find slow queries , you need to log slow queries. you can enable from mysql configuration file my.cnf

tip: use `explain` to let you know what is MySQL doing with your query.

here is the meaning of the values above from phpmyadmin status:

`Slow_queries 11 : "The number of queries that have taken more than long_query_time seconds"`

`Select_full_join  : "The number of joins that do not use indexes. If this value is not 0, you should carefully check the indexes of your tables.`

`Handler_read_next "The number of requests to read the next row in key order. This is incremented if you are querying an index column with a range constraint or if you are doing an index scan. "`

`Handler_read_rnd_next  : "The number of requests to read the next row in the data file. This is high if you are doing a lot of table scans. Generally this suggests that your tables are not properly indexed or that your queries are not written to take advantage of the indexes you have. "`

`Created_tmp_disk_tables  : "The number of temporary tables on disk created automatically by the server while executing statements. If Created_tmp_disk_tables is big, you may want to increase the tmp_table_size value to cause temporary tables to be memory-based instead of disk-based. "`

`Opened_tables : "The number of tables that have been opened. If opened tables is big, your table cache value is probably too small. "`